# How to remove App from App Store and Developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, submit

currently, I have an app ready for sale in the app store. I want to remove it and re-submit a new but identical app using a different account.

I understand that I need to remove the app from the store and I found the steps here

[How to remove an iOS app from the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468262/how-to-remove-app-from-app-store)

However, can I check if it is necessary to delete the app from the old developer's account before resubmitting it via the new account?

Answer (score 5):

To remove an app from the App Store, deselect all territories in your app's Rights and Pricing section on the App Summary page accessible from the Manage Your Applications module. Your app status will change to Developer Removed from Sale and will be removed from the App Store until you make it available again using the Rights and Pricing section.

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 3):

You'll likely need to assign a new Bundle Identifier to your app ... you cannot have an identical bundle identifier on the app store under different accounts.  I believe you'll find that this is the case even if you've removed the app from the initial account, since users may have already installed your app.

Comment: How can I remove the app from an account?

Answer (score 2):

See [Removing an App from Sale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW17%5C) in the *iTunes Connect Developer Guide* which says:

> To remove your app from sale on the store
>
> 1. Open the App Details page for the app, as described in [Creating an iTunes Connect Record for an App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/CreatingiTunesConnectRecord.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1).
> 2. Click Pricing.
> 3. Open the list of store territories.
>
>    - If the app is only available in some territories, the list of territories is displayed.
>    - If the app is available in all territories, open the list of territories by clicking the “specific territories” link.
> 4. Click Deselect All.
> 5. Click Save.
>      The status changes to Developer Removed From Sale. Within 24 hours, your app won’t be seen on the store.
>
> To sell an app you previously removed from sale, you must put it back on sale in the territories you want it to be sold in.
>
> Note:  If you remove a version from sale and then add a new version, the new version will remain Removed from Sale as well, even after it is approved by App Review. To release the new version, you need to clear the app for sale again.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want the app to have the same name then you will have to remove the other one first.