# how to remove the iPhone application version from the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk

I've uploaded the 2.0 version to the appstore having to support both iPhone and iPad.but the previous version does supports only iPhone. This version having the  resolution issues in the iPad. I've created the version 3.0 for iPhone only, but the iTunes connect is not accepting this build and saying that " This bundle does not support one or more of the devices supported by the previous app version. Your app update must continue to support all the devices previously supported.You declare supported devices in Xcode with the Targeted Device Family build setting."

any one please suggest me the best solution.

Comment: Can you clarify what your questions is? What version do you wish to remove from the App Store? Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468262/how-to-remove-app-from-app-store) for instructions on how to remove an application from the App Store.

Comment: Actually version 1.0 supports iPhone only----no issue

Comment: Actually version 1.0 supports iPhone only----no issue          Version 2.0 supports both iPhone and iPad  --- iPad having resolution issue, to solve the resolution issues "I've to recode the total project". So in version 3.0 I've changed the target to iPhone only, but while uploading I am getting an error .             So I want to delete the version 2.0 and upload the version 3.0       Could you please suggest me the best solution for me.

Comment: What is your plan for supporting the iPad? Separate app entirely?

Answer (score 3):

You can't change an app from universal to iPhone or iPad only once it has been approved and was live in the App Store. Your only option is to remove the app from the App Store completely and submit a new one that's iPhone only but then you lose most of your customers probably.

I'd suggest that you just solve whatever issues you have with the universal version as soon as possible and submit an update.

Comment: How to delete the app from the app store or delete from itunes connect