# Remove the App from the App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want to remove my app, which is currently marked "Ready for sale", from the App Store. I could not find any documentation on this, and there is no "Remove from Sale" option in the "Manage Your Apps" section of iTunes Connect. Can anyone guide me on how I can remove my app from the App Store?

I have found one solution here but I'm not able to do it that [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468262/how-to-remove-an-ios-app-from-the-app-store) they mentioned some steps like i have given below.

```
     Go to “Manage Your Applications” and select the app.
     Click “Rights and Pricing” (blue button at the top right.
     Below the availability date and price tier section, you should see a grid of checkboxes for the various countries your app is available in. Click the blue “Deselect All” button.
     Click “Save Changes” at the bottom.
```

But the problem is not not able find the grid checkboxes for the countries. Its showing like this.

[image]

So please tell me how to remove the app from the app store .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click where it says "specific territories" in blue and you'll see the grid.

From there tap the 'deselect all' option and your app will be removed from sale