# How can I remove my app temporarily from the Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

I want to remove app temporarily from Apple app store. In the App Store (formerly iTunes) Connect dashboard under pricing and availability there is an option "**Remove from sale**". Will this remove the app completely ?

I want just to unpublish it for couple of weeks then return it back. If it does so, when I return it back available for sale, will it go again under review ? (same version no new binary).

Answer (score 41):

In the [iTunes Connect's](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps) > **Pricing and Availability** section you can easily switch between

- **Available in all territories or Availability regions (0 of 175 countries or regions)**
- **Remove from sale**

After selecting the right one you can just hit the **Save** button. It will not be removed or added immediately, it takes some time to change state in the AppStore.

[image]

Comment: And it's possible to make it available again later ?

Comment: Just click on "Available in all territories" and hit Save again.

Comment: When you make it available again, will you still have the same ratings and reviews and all that?

Comment: Ratings and reviews seem to stay as is, and become visible publicly once the app is made available again (tested March 2019).

Comment: @Kádi if I select 'Remove from Sale', do I need to pass the manual review again from the apple ?

Comment: no, you do not need to have that binary pass review again - think of it as a switch to make available or not through the app store - in the old days you needed click the checkbox of every territory! Things have gotten a little smoother...

Comment: Will user be able to update to the latest version of an app removed from sale? I issued a last version of my app, I want to remove it from sale, but want users be able to update to the latest of that app.

Comment: If I do remove from sale and needs to update new version, does it goes through app review process

Comment: If you are all worried about removing it from sale (you never know if apple has changed how this works) then just set it to a single small foreign country instead and then switch back to all countries later.  That's what I plan on doing.

Answer (score 28):

You can remove the app from the store **temporarily**.

1. Open [itunesconnect.apple.com](https://itunesconnect.apple.com)
2. Select **My Apps**
3. Select the app you need to remove
4. Select **Pricing and Availability** > **Availability**
5. **Remove from Sale** > **Save**

This will remove the app temporarily from the store. It may take a bit of time to be not available on the App Store. You will have a red dot specifying the developer remove the app from the store.

### How to restore to App Store

Repeat steps 1-4, select which countries you want to restore, then *save*.

### Reviews and Ratings History

By doing the steps above, your reviews and ratings will be intact as long as you don't do anything else. I just restored an app today and everything was as I left it before.

### App Review Afterwards

You do not need to go through app review again as long as you don't change the binary. It takes about 1 hour to get back on to the App Store if you're using a previously approved binary.

A new binary will trigger a new app review.

Comment: if I select 'Remove from Sale', do I need to pass the manual review again from the apple ?

Comment: Nope. If you put it back in the market, it'll use the old binary though, so you can't change anything @Alexa289

Comment: What will happen to the user who already installed the app?

Comment: hey, Thanks for detailed solution. i have followed steps 1-4 again to restore to App Store. how much time will it take to make an effect? as i am unable to find App on Appstore even after Saving settings of Availability there.

Comment: it takes approx. an hour to be back on Appstore. Thanks @craft

Comment: @ShreeSoftech thanks for the follow-up. That timing is in line with my own experience with this as well.

Comment: What if you have an app that is iOS and also Mac Catalyst platform? If you remove, then re-add, can you choose to ONLY publish the iOS, or will it also automatically publish the macOS platform build as well?

Comment: @phiredrop - I can't say for sure. You might have more luck creating a new question for this scenario.

Answer (score 5):

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468262/how-to-remove-an-ios-app-from-the-app-store)

- Open itunesconnect.apple.com
- Go to `Manage Your Applications` and select the app.
- Click `Rights and Pricing` (blue button at the top right.
- Below the availability date and price tier section, you should see a grid of checkboxes for the various countries your app is available in. Click the blue `Deselect All` button.
- Click `Save Changes` at the bottom.

Your app's state will then be `Developer Removed From Sale`, and it will no longer be available on the App Store in any country.

**Example**

[image]

Comment: if I select 'Remove from Sale', do I need to pass the manual review again from the apple ?

Comment: @Alexa289 - not necessary. just you hide your app from live, when you need you can again select your country and and press save button, it will become live.