# Can we temporary hide iOS App from Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, app-store

I would like to hide the app temporarily from Apple app store.

[image]

In above screenshot, there is an option "Remove from sale" in Price and Availability section on iTunes Connect dashboard. If I select "remove from sale" option then will this remove the app completely ?

Will I need to again send the app again on app store for review? 
I want my app to temporary hide/remove from Apple app store. Please suggest.

Comment: Have you looked answers at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329862/remove-app-temporarily-from-apple-app-store?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the app from sale to effectively hide it.

If you don't modify the binary, you won't need another app review process.

You can simply add it to store again later.