# Why is my app's icon displaying incorrectly on the apple App Store?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

I recently released an app on the apple App Store however I have an issue with the app icon not displaying correctly. It displays fine on the App Store when viewed from a MacBook however when viewed from an iPhone the icon is fully black like so:
[image]
The same app listing on the App Store viewed from a MacBook:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case? The icon displays correctly in Xcode and on apple connect yet when viewed from an iPhone on the App Store it turns all black.

Comment: Seeing the same thing right now with App Store connect. My icon which was previously not black is now fully blacked out. Uploaded multiple times but still black. When did you upload this binary?

Comment: check if you have no transparent/alpha colors when making the icon.

Comment: @craft A couple of days ago. The icon was actually also fully blacked out on apple connect for a while but then corrected itself however the App Store listing stayed the same.

Comment: @Pzet - I am also seeing the same thing in App Store connect. I have not changed my icon and has been working for many versions. Now, as I'm about to submit a build for review, I'm seeing the same black icon. Seems like it could be a bug on Apple's side.

Comment: @Pzet - I think I've got a resolution. Check my answer and let me know if that works. Still seems like a bug on Apple's side, but may not be happening all the time. In the meantime, if you wanted to, you could temporarily remove your app if it's bothering you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52839685/5367106

Comment: I have the same problem in the App Store.  I use a CI pipeline to build and upload the app.  For some of the builds, the icon is black in App Store Connect builds page even though the assets have not changed at all.  It's got to be an issue on their side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. The problem was that I was using the flutter package flutter_launcher_icons to generate the app icon and for some reason it did not generate all the right sizes causing the app icon to show up on some devices but not on others. Apple still approved the app which made me think that it was an issue on their side rather than mine. I fixed the issue by using [this app icon generator](https://appicon.co) instead which generated all the right sizes and now the app icon shows up correctly on every device.

Answer (score 1):

Try resubmitting your app. I think it's a current bug with App Store Connect.

When you go into App Store Connect, ensure the icon is displaying properly under the build (on the main version screen). And when you submit the app the for review, also ensure it's displaying properly.

I had the same black icon issue, and after uploading the app a few times, I finally got it to display with the proper icon on the main version screen. And when I submitted for review, it also displayed the proper icon (not the blacked out icon). It took a few attempts.

Comment: Will resubmit and comment on my results when it's accepted

Comment: Even after the multiple resubmit still the problem is not resolved